# Google Cloud load balancer redirect if from a certain region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-storage

I have two static pages (English, Danish) which are currently in *Google Cloud Storage Bucket*. This bucket contains `en` and `dk` folders for those static pages. Also, I have a Load Balancer with *Google CDN* feature.

I want to achieve that when a person connects to the website from Denmark, that person would get the Danish static page. Meanwhile, people outside Denmark would receive the English site.

**How can I achieve this goal in the load balancer level?**

P.s. I think it can be done with `forwardingRules` but I couldn’t figure out how the rules should look like.

P.s.s. I asked the same question in stackoverflow.com but I haven't got any answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets would be the closest way to achieve what you're looking for but as mentioned, this is at a regional level instead of country. From what I can tell, what you're trying to achieve is currently not possible, however it's a good idea to submit as a feature request [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Thank you @EliasH, but it doesn't solve my problem. I've found a way to do this with Load Balancer headers